# Load function from variable name (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, function, variables

Here's a short example of my problem.

```
prefix = "!"
commands = ["right"]
response = nil

message = "Some text !right here"

for i in 0..commands.length
    if message.include?(prefix + commands[i]) # If message contains "!right"
        response = commands[i](parameter) # Load matching function
    end
end

if response
    puts(response)
end

def right(parameter)
    "This is an example response"
end
```

Why can't I load the function `right` by doing it like this?

Comment: I guess it's mainly because Ruby is not JavaScript. 
There are tools to dynamically call methods in Ruby though, like `public_send`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, numeric for loops are usually not used in ruby. You can just write

```
commands.each do |command|
    ...
end
```

As for calling "functions", you need to know that functions as such don't exist in ruby, only methods (which are, in theory, just a special case of function).

To call a *method* on an object, you use the `send` method, which "sends" (read: calls) a "message" (read: the method name) to the object.

The `send` method takes a *symbol* as its argument, which is in practice just an interned string, but you're supposed to use them differently from normal strings.

Last but not least, how can you write `def` outside of any class to define a *function*, but it's still somehow a method? That's because Ruby pretty much wraps your entire code in an implicit object.

---

In practice, you'll be better off using a lambda, which is really just an object with a `call` method that simulates first class functions as you may know them from javascript, lua, etc.

The syntactic sugar for defining one is `whatever = lambda { |argument| puts "I'm a lambda" }` or `whatever = ->(argument){ puts "I'm a lambda too" }`.

`do |argumetn| ... some lines of code ... end` syntax can also be used with both `lambda` and `->` notations.

You can then *call the lambda* with `whatever.call(<argument>)`

There's also Procs, which are like lambdas, but with a few differences and I suggest you just google it if you want to know what exactly they are.

---

Assuming each *command* is a lambda (or a proc), to assign each one to a string, I recommend just using a hash (read: map or dict).

They are defined like this:

```
my_map_variable = {
    20 => "I'm an integer",
    "string" => "I'm a string",
    :symbol => "I'm a symbol, an interned string",
    symbol2: "I'm the same as above, but with fancy notation",
    right: -> (parameter) { puts "This is an example response" }
}
```

You can then access the values like this

```
puts my_map_variable[20] # prints: I'm an integer
puts my_map_variable[:symbol2]
puts my_map_variable[:right].call(nil) # prints: "This is an example response"
```

Lastly, if you have a string `"right"`, but your hash uses symbol indices, you can just call `"right".to_sym` to turn the string into a symbol. Or you can just use strings in the first place.